Could someone please explain this Perl method?
Unfortunately, I have inherited a very large Perl codebase and I need to do some modifications to one of its features.
The program is reading a CSV file and does some cleanup on it to create a protobuf message. There is a key value pair foo:bar in a temp_params{} part of the input string.
I managed to trace where I think the temp_params are getting parsed. For now, please ignore dp, let's assume that dp will always be empty. The Key-value I'm expecting is part of tp, not dp.
sub _add_temp_and_dynamic_params {
    my ($self, $row) = @_;

    state $raw_to_full = {
        tp => 'temp_params',
        dp => 'dynamic_params',
    };

    while ( my ( $raw, $full ) = each %$raw_to_full ) {
        my @params =
            map { { key => $_->[0], value => $_->[1] } }
            grep { @$_ == 2 && $_->[0] ne '' }
            map { [ split ":" ] }
            split /,/, ( delete $row->{ $raw } or next );
        $row->{ $full }->@* = @params if @params;
    }
}

After this, I want to call _my_new_subroutine with the output of that method above, and the goal of that method is to take that temp_params{foo:bar} so that foo:bar ends up as its own independent key-value pair
The problem is: I really have no idea what is going on in this method or how the output looks like. This looks extremely cryptic to me. I don't know how raw_to_full could contain any meaningful info, since it seems that it's just creating a hash where the key is tp and the value is the string 'temp_params'. I'm not even sure if my method will need to work with a hash or with a string. What does ( delete $row->{ $raw } or next ) even mean? or $row->{ $full }->@* = @params if @params;? I heard many times that Perl had the ill-fame of being a "write-only language", but I had no idea it would be this bad.
So far, what I understand is:
Method assigns the $self variable because perl methods always pass their own caller as an argument. Then $row is added. The $ indicates scalar, and this is operating on csv lines, so I assume that the input is a string.
Then, a local variable $raw_to_full is being declared, this is a hash where tp and dp are keys, and strings 'temp_params' and 'dynamic_params' are their respective values. (This also leads to another question: if this is a hash, why is this being indicated with a $ instead of a %?)
Then, 2 new local variables are created: raw and full, which are the result of "Spliting" the key and the values in each entry in the raw_to_full hash.
For every iteration, a string is created where the word 'key' is actually declared as key itself, and the value of key is the 'raw' value whereas 'full' is the value (not so sure about this.
Then a filter is done to only include rows with key-value, where the value is not empty.
Then, a split is created at where ':' is indicated.
Lastly, another split is done to separate I assume the different kv pairs inside of each "params" string.
After that, I'm completely lost as to what could be happening here.

Yes. dp is not needed at the moment (there's different keys there, the key I want is coming in tp)

I did, but I don't see how the existence of dp changes the functionality of the method. It will still execute the same set of instructions for both kv in the hash, no?

Maybe also remove the "write only" comment if you want people familiar with Perl to be friendly. In fact, these lines are not something obscure and it only shows you can't read it.

delete $row->{ $raw } or next removes a key from the hash reference $row. The associated value is returned and if it's false, next iteration of the enclosing loop is started. $row->{ $full }->@* = @params if @params; is an alternative way of writing @{ $row->{ $full } } = @params if @params, i.e. if there are @params, they are assigned to the array reference stored at $row->{$full}.

if this is a hash, why is this being indicated with a $ instead of a %? Read about references in Perl.

OK, so $raw_to_full is an anonymous hash...but if the value is literally just the string "temp_params" (or dynamic), how does that contain any meaningful info?

It seems to translate tp and dp into their full equivalents.

Anyone asked to work on a program written in language X without knowing the language is going to have a hard time. Don't blame perl here.

(though the delete bit does look like the author is being clever for the sake of being clever, the rest looks pretty straightforward. Would it help if the map/grep/map bit was split into separate statements with intermediate variables?)

@Shawn Right... deleting.

Using state seems like a premature optimization, as it's purpose is to initialize a variable only once and save that state through the runtime. Since the variable is never changed in this block, the purpose of state becomes that it only initializes the variable once. So perhaps an attempt at saving a few cpu cycles?

@Dasph For future reference, you should not be this verbose when writing a question. Try to figure out what is important, and be minimal.

"The problem is: I really have no idea what is going on in this method .... I heard many times that Perl had the ill-fame of being a "write-only language", but I had no idea it would be this bad."  -- The problem is that you don't know the language. It's that simple.  (Has nothing to do with Perl itself, whose 'write-only' label related to its early years -- justly or not -- and lost any relevance decades ago.)

Use a dumping tool to look at your data structure. You'll find that it takes
$row = {
   tp => "foo:bar,abc:def",
};

and changes it into
$row = {
   temp_params => [
      { key => "foo", value => "bar" },
      { key => "abc", value => "def" },
   ],
];

This format makes it hard to access params by key, but it allows multiple params with the same key.
To find the values for a key, you will need to iterate over the array.
my @values_for_foo =
   map { $_->{ value } }
      grep { $_->{ key } eq "foo" }
         $row->{ temp_params }->@*;

That said, you only keep the last value for any given key. (So why use this structure?!?) To get the only value for a key (or undef if not found),
my ( $value_for_foo ) =
   map { $_->{ value } }
      grep { $_->{ key } eq "foo" }
         $row->{ temp_params }->@*;


Specific questions asked:

delete $row->{ $raw } is the same as $row->{ $raw }, except it deleted the element from the hash in the process.
or next goes to the next pass of the loop if the left-hand side operand is false. It's presumably meant to check if $row->{ temp_params } exists.
$row->{ $full }->@* is the same as @{ $row->{ $full } }, i.e. th array referenced by $row->{ $full }.
I would write $row->{ $full }->@* = @params as $row->{ $full } = \@params.
You assume that the $row is a string, but it needs to be a reference to a hash for $row->{ } to be valid.
$raw_to_full is technically holds a reference to a hash, not a hash.
$raw and $full are indeed the key and value (e.g. tp and temp_params) of one of the elements.
You're reading backwards. f( g( h() ) ) calls h first.

split /,/, "foo:bar,abc:def" produces "foo:bar", "abc:def"
These are passed to map { [ split ":" ] }, which produces [ "foo", "bar" ], [ "abc", "def" ]
These are passed to the filter.
These are passed to map { { key => $_->[0], value => $_->[1] } }, which produces { key => "foo", value => "bar" }, { key => "abc", value => "def" }.



Please limit your Question to one problem in the future.


I heard many times that Perl had the ill-fame of being a "write-only language", but I had no idea it would be this bad.

Except for the "hidden" or next and the improvement I suggested above, this is actually extremely readable. Your problem is that you don't even know the basics. Not knowing the language doesn't mean not readable.
Since you're comparing to Python,
Perl:
my @params =
   map { { key => $_->[0], value => $_->[1] } }
      grep { @$_ == 2 && $_->[0] ne '' }
         map { [ split /:/ ] }
            split /,/,
               $row->{ $raw };

Python:
tmp = row[ "raw" ].split( "," )
tmp = [ x.split( ":" ) for x in tmp ]
tmp = [ x for x in tmp if len( x ) == 2 and x[ 1 ] != "" ]
params = [ { "key": x[ 0 ], "value": x[ 1 ] } for x in tmp ]

yikes! So, even though every language strives to add functional programming features,[1] we're forced to abandon the functional programming approach and use loops.
params = []
for x in row[ raw ].split( "," ):
   tmp = x.split( ":" )
   if len( tmp ) == 2 and tmp[ 1 ] != "":
      params.append( { "key": tmp[ 0 ], "value": tmp[ 1 ] } )

ok, despite the inflexibility of Python, we managed to write something readable. It just took a lot more work. Just to get back what looks almost identical to the Perl program (in the opposite order).
Note that you have the option of using this style in Perl too.
my @params;
for my $x ( split( /,/, $row->{ $raw } ) ) {
   my @tmp = split( /:/, $x );
   if ( @tmp == 2 && $tmp[ 1 ] ne "" ) {
      push @params, { "key": tmp[ 0 ], "value": tmp[ 1 ] };
   }
}



To name some, Perl, C#, C++, JS, Lua, Raku and especially Python (function pointers, list comprehensions). This is basically every language I have some knowledge of except C.
For example, the following is how I'd write it in C#, which is virtually identical to the Perl version:
row[ raw ]
   .split( "," )
      .Select( _ => _.split( ":" ) )
         .Where( _ => _.Count == 2 && _[ 1 ] != "" )
            .Select( _ =>
               new Dictionary<string, string>()
                  { "key", _[ 0 ], "value", _[ 1 ] }
            );




$row->{ $full }->@* = @params is a weird way of writing $row->{ $full } = \@params. Is it? The second way propagates changes to @params to $row->{$full}, the first one doesn't.

@choroba, You've proved my point. The purpose of this sub is to create $row->{ temp_params } from $row->{ tp }. You're saying the current code implies something already has a copy of the reference in $row->{ temp_params }. But we haven't created that reference yet. So yes, $row->{ $full } = \@params is definitely the clearer way of writing it.

Thank you for helping me in deciphering this. I know SO is not a place for discussion, but if you're curious about my thoughts on Perl, I feel this post by "dusktreader" greatly explains them: https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/v2dwax/why_is_perl_perceived_as_old_and_obsolete_and/
This isn't my first time trying Perl, and every time, I run into the same roadblocks that most people describe. The extreme flexibility just ends up being a problem for me.

The answer to the title question, Python is not nearly as old as it claim that post claims. There might have been a Python then, but it would have been a different from the language of now. Perl is much much older, but its age shows a bit. Readability has nothing to do with it.  It's the lack of sandboxing, the fact that it's C heritage leaks through, the lack of text streams by default.

It's a much much nicer language than Python, though. For something more modern, I'd use C# over Python. The top reply effectively complaining that there are $ everywhere. Which is about the only part of your question you got right!? So is that really a valid complaint?

I've added a Python conversion to my answer.

You removed most of the noise from the perl part, which comes from all the boilerplate needed to prepare the input, whereas in python you'd just have to specify that the method receives one parameter, and calling it with more than that would lead to very clear errors.
I personally work with Scala, though, not Python. But yes, Perl is A LOT noisier and harder to read. The thing is: We could show this code to people who have no idea about programming and they'd be able to at least roughly infer what the python one is doing. For the Perl version, they would be totally clueless.

But in any case, the question is solved and SO is not really for discussions, so let's agree to disagree about the current status and form of perl.

Re "You removed most of the noise from the perl part", Nope, I just added spaces. I didn't convert the whole code to keep things short and because there was nothing interesting in the rest. { tp => "temp_params", dp => "dynamic_params" } becomes { "tp": "temp_params", "dp": "dynamic_params" }, etc.

@ikegami You did remove the delete and or next part, but otherwise identical. Indentation can do wonders for readability. :)

@TLP, I already said in my answer that the or next part is badly written. It should have been done separately. The fact that a part was badly written doesn't make Perl unreadable. Just that code. You can write unreadable code in Python too.

You didn't just add spaces, you left out the initial my ($self, $row) = @_; (and future calls to my and all these internal variable declarations, which is undoubtedly a huge part of the noise that people who dislike perl complain about)

Is it noise, though? A Perl programmer parses that at a glance. And Perl has signatures now: sub _add_temp_and_dynamic_params( $self, $row ), as compared to def _add_temp_and_dynamic_params( self, row ):).

Yes, it is noise. That's the point from the start: it's not intuitive at all. The only way you can make sense of it is by being very familiar with the syntax and all the implicits workings of the language. If you give it to someone who has never programmed, they're not gonna figure it out, whereas they probably will get a general idea of what is happening in Python. Whereas other languages would just call a setter/update like foo.update(newVals), perl ends up calling  $row->{$full}->@*=@params, which is not intuitive to anyone not familiar with the syntax.

Also, you don't need to declare self for the python signature, the method doesn't have to be aware of the caller as it would simply return a new object. Lastly: I find your python conversion a bit disingenous, as you're simply "writing perl in python". Approaching the problem in an actual python fashion would be trivial, as you'd simply have to call some csv reader that will convert the tp string to a dict, then update the desired field by getting the value from the dict. No need for list comprehensions or calls to functors.

Re "That's the point from the start: it's not intuitive at all.", Doing a list assignment is one of the most fundamental operations of the language. Intuition doesn't come into play. The first time you saw 4 + 3, you would have had no idea what it did. Intuition wouldn't have helped you. It doesn't make it unreadable. Again, you're confusing not knowing the language and readability. Those are different things. You apparently expect to be able to read a language you don't know, but you shouldn't expect that.

Re "I find your python conversion a bit disingenous, as you're simply "writing perl in python".", Not Perl programming, functional programming. You know, the thing every other language supports because it makes things so easy and clear and flexible. Python provides all the tools for functional programming, but it's so damn noisy. Instead of writing your code as a sequence of operations, Python forces you to use nested loop which results in far more code and a higher mental tax since it's no longer a sequence of operations but a repeating sequences of operations.

I don't expect to know all of its intricacies but I do HOPE to get a general picture of what is going on. This isn't the first time I've picked up a codebase in an unknown language, but it has been the "hardest". If you don't know Scala and I ask you what val allMyNums = List(1, 2) ++ List(3, 4) does, you would very easily infer the answer, even if you didn't know programming il. In Perl it wouldn't be like that because the syntax is full significant punctuation that looks like noise to outsiders. It's not by chance that one of the most common criticisms of perl is its unintuitive syntax.

None of your problems was with the punctuation. You knew what $ meant. You knew what @$_ == 2 did.  You know what [] and {} means cause it's the same as Python. Who's actually the disingenuous one? What you didn't understand is that given f g h (short for f( g( h() ) ), you thought f was called first. And you probably didn't look up what the map function did either. Your problems had nothing to do with readability.

The core of my problem is that its nearly impossible to infer what is going on in that code, because the syntax is full of non alphanumeric symbols, each of which has a very significant effect. Also just passing a dict and returning a dict copy with the appended new value would still be functional, and you wouldn't have to deal with any of the noise you complained about. Anyway, I'll leave now, need to study some perl to hopefully decomission this component and rewrite it in a more maintainable language.

Re "I ask you what val allMyNums = List(1, 2) ++ List(3, 4) does, you would very easily infer the answer,", List( 3, 6 ), but maybe List( 1, 2, 3, 4 ). I don't know what it does because I don't know the language. It's 100% readable even if I don't know what it does. You're still confusing not knowing the language with readability.

Re "The core of my problem is that its nearly impossible to infer what is going on in that code", That makes it EASIER.  Cause it helps you classify the tokens. And it helps you figure out which are less important to focus one. With Python, it's harder to figure out which words to focus one since all you have is words. in the very code in this examples, I can clearly see we split, then transform, filter and transform. I can easily see the first transform splits into an array. I can easily see the second transform builds a hash. This is the very definition of readable.

Not being able to guess what code does when you don't know the language is not a measure of readability. That's simply wishing all the languages were the same. Having different languages is a good thing. The fact that you don't know Sweedish doesn't make it unreadable. The fact that you don't know Perl doesn't make it unreadable.

Perl's readability is why I like it so much more than Python. The rigidity that is the cornerstone of Python might make programs more consistent in appearance, but it always ends up coming at the cost of readability.

(See update, where I included more readable Python code)

Heh, this is going to be buried, but typically I see an array of hashes where what seems like the hash key ('keyhere) can be repeated. The spec might be something likefoo:bar,foo:defsometimes. For a concrete example, I have an API I suffer through that has[ { attr => ..., value => ... }, { attr => ..., value => ...}]. The attr` value seems like it should be the key, but then it's really hard to tell the difference between repeated occurances of a repeatable field and a single occurance of that field that has multiple values.

@brian d foy, yeah, the answer mentions the structure allows repeated keys. ("it allows multiple params with the same key") It also mentions that the code doesn't support repeated keys. ("you only keep the last value for any given key.") /// I think you're leading to the suggestion of replacing [ { attr =>..., value => ... }, { attr =>..., value => ... } ] with { attr => [ ...values... ] }. I concur.

I'm not suggesting that because in the stuff I work with that's different than repeating them in distinct hashes. I tried moving to that data structure and broke everything :)

@Dasph  I just have to add, using this statement of yours (my emphasis): "The only way you can make sense of it is by being very familiar with the syntax and all the implicits workings of the language. If you give it to someone who has never programmed, they're not gonna figure it out, whereas they probably will get a general idea of what is happening in Python."  --- (1), Yes, you need to know the language (2) No, you cannot sensibly work with a language you don't know.  (This thread already provides many good details for these statements.)

@Dasph [contd]  An example: I do or have done production-grade work with more than a half dozen languages but I can't really tell, beyond pointless guessing, what your Scala code sample does.  I'd have to look it up. (Very much the same holds for Python.  I still remember starting with it, the "friendly" language ... gah! Couldn't get anything.  Just had to learn it first :)

@briandfoy "...that's different than repeating them in distinct hashes..."  -- time to write a class for it, instead?  (I don't really know your problem of course, please excuse mine guessing... but I'm just now struggling with a problem of a need for a strange complex data structure and a class (composition) seems to be solving it, as usual. In Python btw)

@zdim, I think bdf is talking about a situation which allows for both foo=abc+def (one key, two values) and foo=abc,foo=def (duplicate key, one value each)??? But the approach I suggested could still handle that. foo => [ [ "abc", "def" ] ] vs foo => [ [ "abc" ], [ "def" ] ] /// A case that can't be handled by the structure I mentioned is when order relative to other keys matters. e.g. when foo=x,bar=1,foo=y is different than foo=x,foo=y,bar=1. (This is one of the problems with XML::Simple.)

@ikegami "...a situation which allows for both..." -- right, where one can't collapse the same keys ... what I meant to say is that I find that once a complex data structure gets too complex or entangled or weird ... writing a class (or classes) for the data (instead of using a nested complex data structure)  can make it more manageable.  But I'm really merely guessing not knowing their problem...

Why isn't there a LOGO solution? :-) Sorry. I just returned to this question after 2 days and found you seem to have answered it in every reasonable language available. Brilliant!
